# Selenium Proxy IP Address Configuration IP Not Correct

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, webdriver, http-proxy

I have paid/rented a proxy server in brazil

```
String proxyAddress = "myusername:myuserpass123@196.18.199.51:15464"
proxy.setAutodetect(false);
proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyAddress);
proxy.setSslProxy(proxyAddress);
chromeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

I m running the webdriver on my local computer and I am in Indonesia. When the chrome browser opens up, I can debug and made sure that capabilities were set correctly: I can see the manual proxy setting set to the correct address string above.
However, when webdriver opens https://api.ipify.org/?format=json, it still returns my IP in Indonesia. What am I Missing here? My expectation is because I had configured webdriver to be proxied by a server in Brazil, https://api.ipify.org/?format=json should return Brazilian IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using Selenium 4 BiDirectional API** (https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/bidi_api/)

> **Register Basic Auth**.
> Some applications make use of browser authentication to secure pages. With Selenium, you can automate the input of basic auth credentials whenever they arise.

```
//C#
//Console App .NET 6

using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
var proxyAddress = "address:port";
proxy.HttpProxy = proxyAddress;
proxy.SslProxy = proxyAddress;

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.Proxy = proxy;

IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

NetworkAuthenticationHandler handler = new NetworkAuthenticationHandler()
{
    UriMatcher = (d) => d.Host.Contains("your-domain.com"), // or set it `true` to enable proxy everywhere
    Credentials = new PasswordCredentials("admin", "password")
};

INetwork networkInterceptor = driver.Manage().Network;
networkInterceptor.AddAuthenticationHandler(handler);
await networkInterceptor.StartMonitoring();

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json");

await networkInterceptor.StopMonitoring();
```

Comment: two years later buttttt...in which library/assemble does NetworkAuthenticationHandler live?

Comment: Nvmd, the program was on vintage Selenium (2.35) package