# C# Selenium - How to use proxy with Authentication?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I've been struggling for two days and couldn't find a solution. I tried it first with mozilla firefox. Then I tried with google chrome and got the same error again.
How do I add the proxy feature to the browser? More precisely, how can I run it by adding user properties?

It gets stuck when it comes to "networkInterceptor.StartMonitoring()" code. The browser opens but the page does not load.

If I enter the link manually after the browser opens, it requires username and password.

Note : Also, is there a different method?

Version : Selenium Webdriver 4.0.0

Codes:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

private async void Create()
{
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
    var proxyAddress = "host:port";
    proxy.HttpProxy = proxyAddress;
    proxy.SslProxy = proxyAddress;

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.Proxy = proxy;

    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    NetworkAuthenticationHandler handler = new NetworkAuthenticationHandler()
    {
        UriMatcher = (d) => true,
        Credentials = new PasswordCredentials("user", "password")
    };

    INetwork networkInterceptor = driver.Manage().Network;
    networkInterceptor.AddAuthenticationHandler(handler);
    await networkInterceptor.StartMonitoring();

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.google.com");

    await networkInterceptor.StopMonitoring();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium Proxy IP Address Configuration IP Not Correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70821656/selenium-proxy-ip-address-configuration-ip-not-correct)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working for me. :/

Comment: It works when I remove user:pass, but it doesn't work otherwise.

Comment: Do you use selenium 4?

Comment: I tried many versions. Tried in the version you specified, but the result was unsuccessful.

Comment: Update your question with adding some code of doing what you have already tried, because i can confirm that its working in my machine

Comment: I updated. Can you check again?

Comment: Does this help you?

Comment: Thank you george for your interest in the question. I solved the problem by following the method in the link below.
https://www.webkoz.net/selenium-webdriver-proxy-kullanimi

Answer (score 0):

I think that the question must become: why selenium's method: `await networkInterceptor.StartMonitoring();` doesn't work on windows forms.
This occurs because windows forms is single threaded application. So in order to make it to work you might call the create method as below:

```
//First change your `Create()` method to return a Task instead of void.
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Create();
    });
}
```