# Selenium C# Proxy Authentification

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use Selenium in my work machine but when I try to initialize
the `ChromeDriver` or any browser driver, for example:

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();  
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://lambdatest.github.io/sample-todo-app/");
```

I am getting this error:

> System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.'

My machine is under proxy, is there any additional configuration to make this works ?

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70821656/selenium-proxy-ip-address-configuration-ip-not-correct ?

Comment: the probleme that it crashes in the initialization of ChromeDriver
the web browser does not open at all

Comment: Share your code pls

Comment: Please [edit] you question to include the code. Do not post code in comments. It is too difficult to read.